# Is it possible to require min and max string length for param in wsdl file?

Tags: soap, wsdl

I am creating a web service using php SOAPServer. I am creating a wsdl file and looking for info on how to set the min and max string length for one of the input parameters for one of the web service operations. Is it even possible?

By the way I am using soap binding style "rpc"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you code the WSDL by hand or does the library create it for you by looking at an endpoint class? If you are coding the WSDL by hand, you could simply add something like this in your schema descriptor:

```
<simpleType name="MyStringType">
      <restriction base="string">
         <minLength value="10" />
         <maxLength value="30" />
      </restriction>
   </simpleType>
   <element name="greetMe">
      <complexType>
         <sequence>
            <element name="requestType" 
               type="tns:MyStringType"/>
         </sequence>
      </complexType>
   </element>
```

Comment: I am using Eclipse, it has a tool to design wsdl file, but it's not very user-friendly tool, not very intuitive. Anyway, thanks for your answer, I also found a way to do this in Eclipse. What I don't understand is why the SoapUP or php SOAPClient do not complain when I enter a 2-char string when the min length is defined as 3 chars in wsdl?

Comment: @DmitriSnytkine Can you try something like this:  <br/> 
    $client = new SoapClient("https://yourservice?wsdl",
        array(  'trace'      => true,
                'exceptions' => true,
             )

    );

Answer (score 0):

Its probably because the service's validation is turned off. Check your framework and see if there is a flag that needs to be set in one of the xml's (application-context.xml) for the service config.